# Javascript or RoR for wide range of apps?

Tags: javascript, ruby, web

I am fairly new to web development but am eager to start learning how to build web applications. My plan is to settle on a language now that I can focus entirely on, so that in the coming 6 months, I will be competent enough to build a "wide" range of web apps.

These apps could range from simple calculators or interactive builders like;

> http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp
>   [The Apple Store product builder](http://store.apple.com/au/configure/MD104X/A?)

To full blown services like Groupon.

I'd settled on **Ruby on Rails** after some research (instead of Python/Django). But realized later that it wouldn't be the most appropriate for the smaller applications I want done.

On the other hand, I've noticed that a lot of larger, more complex services *can* be built with **Javascript**. This got me thinking that I could dedicate myself to Javascript, and have the competency in a few months to develop all the kinds of applications that I mentioned above. Instead of wasting the next 6 months of my life though (maybe not so much wasting as misallocating), I thought I'd ask some experts.

**So, can learning purely Javascript allow me to create applications ranging in size from small calculators, to Groupon/Twitter sized services, or will I need to learn RoR instead?**

Thanks in advance for any help! Apologies if I haven't worded the question properly too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Learn both JavaScript and Ruby on Rails.

They are complimentary technologies.

For "small calculators" you'll probably want to use JavaScript since it's likely that everything would be done on the client-side (in the web browser) instead of round-tripping to the server.

For any backend work (on the web server) that requires persistence to a database, communication with third party APIs, specialized calculations, etc. you'll want to use RoR.

By becoming skilled at both frontend technologies (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) and backend (Ruby on Rails) you will have made good progress towards your plan to "be competent enough to build a 'wide' range of web apps."

Comment: Thanks for the response maerics!